# Condition over a column that i just create

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't solve a problem with a sql query.

I have a table that contains something like this:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
| A1   | B1   | C    |
| A2   | B2   | D    |
| A3   | B3   | E    |
| A3   | B3   | D    |
+------+------+------+
```

and a want to select only the row that have an unique Col3 if Col1 and Col2 have the same value.

So the result should be:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
| A1   | B1   | C    |
| A2   | B2   | D    |
+------+------+------+
```

Because row 3 and 4 have a similar Col1 and Col2 but a different Col3.

I need to put a condition over a new column that I create during the query and i can't manage how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple group by if I understand you correctly:

```
select col1, col2, min(col3) as col3
from the_table
group by col1, col2
having count(distinct col3) = 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `COUNT(DISTINCT col3) = 1`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: probably yes (the sample data doesn't require it, but if I re-read the question, then you are right). Thanks